# Would "old formula" oil paints be available, and would they go on smoother?

Tags: paint, oil-based-paint

This is probably not the right subject line - I'm not after the stuff in tubes, that artists use, but the kind of paint I remember was used in the past, well probably 40 - 50 years ago, that we used to call oil paint.

The thing is, whenever I try to use the modern, jelly-like paints with a brush, it seems to be impossible to get the smooth surface that I prefer. It always ends up with stripes, and using a roller doesn't really do the job either, it tends to leave a sort of rippled surface; and any way, I just want to use a really good paint brush and do a good job. Not as efficiently as a professional, sure, but I have the time to just enjoy a job being done well, even if I have to paint several times with.

So, after this initial whine of nostalgia, is it still possible to get 'proper oil paint' - the kind that runs if you put too much on and doesn't stand up in furrows?

Comment: If you're finding that your paint is too thick, just add a bit of _paint thinner_ to it, mix thoroughly, and you discover that you've got... _thinner paint_. What else are you looking for? Thinning paint (of any type) is very common and is usually _required_ if you're spraying, so it doesn't even violate any of the use instructions on the can.

Comment: For environmental reasons (mostly), most paint is now latex (water based) instead of oil. There are exceptions for specific applications. **What are you painting?**

Comment: @FreeMan I know that, of course. What else am I looking for? I just enjoy learning the manual craft skills; I also use manual saws (that I sharpen and set myself), manual planes (...) and so on, simply because I enjoy it. Paint also used to be something rather simple along the lines of linseed oil + colour, but at the moment I just want to know about what was used some 50 years ago.

Comment: "I just want to know about what was used some 50 years ago" no problem with that! Have you done some research to find out on your own? If so, share what you've found and why it doesn't answer your question. Also, [edit[ your question to explicitly ask that - your current question asks if it's possible to get this kind which, really, is a shopping question and that's [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 4):

The only true "old fashioned" oil (*not alkyd; see note below*) paint that is still being made that I'm aware of is made by Fine Paints of Europe. Their premier oil paint is called Hollandlac. The paints are sold in various metric size containers, the largest being 2.5 liter which is 2/3 of a gallon.

These paints can't be shipped to a few restrictive states (you can guess which ones) and the largest container can't be shipped to certain other states, so if you live in one of those states you'd have to buy in mini containers.

And now the kicker: the current price (2023) for the largest container is equivalent to $265/gal plus shipping for plain white. Other colors may have surcharges.

**Alkyd paint** as manufactured today usually contains no oil, but a polyester resin that behaves similar to a drying oil when used as a paint. (Alkyd is almost universally called "oil paint", the name of the product that it replaced.) True old fashioned oil paint contains a "drying oil", that is, an oil that polymerizes when exposed to atmospheric oxygen. Linseed oil is the most commonly used drying oil.

Comment: OP's use of "colour" (in a comment) is a pretty good indicator that he's used to buying things by the liter (or litre) and won't have to worry about shipping across The Pond.

Comment: I've seen people obtain it in restrictive states; they had to buy it in quarts. Many quarts.  Wonderful stuff.

Comment: Given the 5-year timescale in the question, the OP is probably thinking of alkyd paints.  They were [first sold in 1932](http://www.vam.ac.uk/content/journals/conservation-journal/issue-44/problems-associated-with-the-use-of-gloss-house-hold-paints-by-20th-century-artists/) and widespread since the 50s (in formulations that still included some linseed oil in the darker colours but not the light ones as it turns yellow; other oils were used instead). So "Alkyd paint contains no oil" may or may not be true for most modern alkyd paints you can buy; it's certainly not true historically

Comment: @ChrisH That's 50 years. Good points; answer edited to comport with history as revealed here.

Comment: @FreeMan Let's not forget our colourful Canadian friends who *would* have to ship across the pond. Really, there ought to be a preformatted template when the new question box opens so you can fill-in location. It's required info for so many questions in DIY and so often left out.

Comment: Those darn Canadians. My apologies, I do tend to forget about them and their affinity for British monarchs.

Comment: Sorry, typo - luckily I quoted dates that make it fairly obvious (@MTA)

Comment: Thank you for answering my original question - the title change wasn't mine, certainly. Strangely I wasn't alerted about it.

Answer (score 1):

"Non-drip gloss" (a bit of a misnomer - it does run if you put too much on) is probably the runniest gloss. It's becoming less common - B&Q (the biggest DIY retailer in the UK) only sell it in black or white - but is what I remember from 35 years ago.

Trade gloss from Johnstone's or Leyland might be worth a look too.  Obviously avoid anything that says one-coat.

I'd say exterior glosses behave more like you're asking for, but I tend to use water-based wood/metal paints indoors these days.

Answer (score 1):

The new stuff is called "latex" (which is not accurate at all) or "emulsion" paint.  It's not that new; it's been around for ages certainly 50 years, and its virtue is that it has far, far, far less "off-gassing" than alkyds or traditional oils.  Which means a dwelling can be turned around quickly; the homeowner won't have to ventilate the room for days to avoid choking on the fumes.  It is also water-based, which makes for ridiculously easy clean-up.  As such, it has dominated the architectural coatings space as long as I can remember, and I bought the very last can of actual red lead primer from a paint manufacturer.

But also, the stuff has far, far less VOC (Volatile Organic Compounds aka "paint thinner"); and that caught the interest of the environmental quality folks.  So they have mandated it for architectural coatings, and pushed the VOC down so low that mold and fungus can thrive in the paint can.  And in the usual way they do regulations, they design the regulation so the economic incentive is to comply, but a committed zealot still is free to do the other thing, it'll just cost them more.   So for instance you can still get "oil based" aka alkyd paints in quarts.

By the way given your timeframe, I think you're really thinking of alkyd paints.

> is it still possible to get 'proper oil paint' - the kind that runs if you put too much on and doesn't stand up in furrows?

Yes, of course it is. I use it almost exclusively, and a lot on architecture even.  You just need to take some antibiotics for that bad case of Big Box Fever lol.

Consumers get into this mindset that they're only allowed to buy things at "mall type" places with well lit parking lots and welcoming stores. And that means Home Depot, Lowes, your local family owned ACE affiliate, and the various Benjamin Moore and Sherwin Williams outposts they stick in residential areas.  All of whom deal exclusively in latex paint.  Except for the hardware stores may have Rustoleum in quarts and gallons, but it can't be tinted.  Because of those economic incentives, alkyds have been obliterated from shops which specialize in architectural paint.

However, if you go to Sherwin Williams industrial locations, they'll cheerfully sell you **everything**.  Not only will they have alkyds (and I suspect you really are thinking of alkyds), they'll have several grades of it and clear up on into epoxies and aliphatic LPUs (spray only).

Next, go to a chandlery (that's a marine supply house)... they'll have even more stuff including some traditional stuff, and including LPUs *formulated for brush* which is the only safe way to apply that stuff.

And of course there's Fine Paints of Europe.  But I think you'll be fine with alkyd paints. You just need to get reacquainted.

> The thing is, whenever I try to use the modern, jelly-like paints with a brush, it seems to be impossible to get the smooth surface that I prefer.

Architectural people don't like smooth surfaces. They reveal every blemish. They want at the very least, roller stipple and they will often splatter mud and only half-level it, to create a mottled surface on purpose.

First, use the right kind of brush for latex.  Natural bristle, correct for most other paints, is a disaster with latex - it just waterlogs.  You have to use a synthetic brush made for latex.  Second, consider ["roll and tip"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TK8A82dVJDE) as a method - the roller evenly distributes the paint then you just go swish-swish with the brush.  This is important because latex dries quickly and gives you very little working time.  So I use a small 3-4" roller.   It can help to maintain high humidity in the room.